# Simple Spacing In Output

Tags: java, string, spacing

I need to write a method which will take a string like `"1+2+3*4"` and add spaces between each and every character, and remove spaces if there are too many. The string passed in may have spaces / not have spaces, I need to assure there is only one space in between each character.

If someone could please provide the simplest and least complicated way of achieving this, I would be very grateful.

Comment: What have you already tried? What problems did you have? What programming language are you using? Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's my first time here. Forgot to include that.
I am programming in java, and I have tried using a for loop to go through the string and finding two characters beside each other, and if they were null I'd add a space in between. I need to do this because it is part of a larger project, this part if validating the user's input, because the rest of my program requires the formula to be in spaced out form.

Comment: As mentioned above, it's part of a larger, calculator-type program I'm making, but yes the project is to be completed for school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution normalizes the whitespace around each operator.

```
return expr.replaceAll("(?<=\\d)\\s*([-+/*])\\s*(?=\\d)", " $1 ");
```

Comment: This is great, but i really need something more simple. 
I want to be able to understand what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Usually understandable code is better.

A more understandable, brute-force approach, probably slower, with no tricky regular expressions, uses String.replace.

1. Remove every space.  e.g. `String.replace(" ", "");`
2. Then replace every operator with the operator with spaces, e.g.  `String.replace("+", " + ");`

e.g. full code (warning - not tested!)

```
 static final String[] ALL_MY_OPS = { "+", "-", "*", "//"};

 public static String cleanup(String in) {
    String result = in.replace(" ", "");  // remove all spaces
    for (String op : ALL_MY_OPS) {
       String replacement = " " + op + " ";
       result = result.replace(op, replacement);
    }

    return result;
 }
```